# Avro Writer in Python 3.5

Tags: python, apache, python-3.x, avro

I'm attempting to create an Avro based on an existing schema, but I'm getting an error while using the syntax from the tutorial located [here](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedpython.html). The console is saying the 'bytes' object has no attribute 'to_json', but it's deep within the Avro library. Are there any good workarounds or ways to fix this error?

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "build_data.py", line 15, in <module>
al.create_avro(logs)
File "AppLog.py", line 57, in create_avro
writer = DataFileWriter(open("new.avro", "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg/avro/datafile.py", line 151, in __init__
self.SetMeta('avro.schema', str(writer_schema).encode('utf-8'))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg/avro/schema.py", line 266, in __str__
return json.dumps(self.to_json())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.1-py3.5.egg/avro/schema.py", line 808, in to_json
to_dump['items'] = item_schema.to_json(names)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'to_json'
```

Code:

```
schema = avro.schema.ArraySchema(open("AppLogs.avsc", "rb").read())
writer = DataFileWriter(open("new.avro", "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation linked to [in the question](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedpython.html) is out of date. I was able to fix the above by changing the schema method call to `Parse` and removing the `b` from "open".

Here's the updated code:

```
schema = avro.schema.Parse(open("AppLogs.avsc", "r").read())
writer = DataFileWriter(open(new_avro, "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)
```